# Hyperledger environment variables passed to docker container running chaincode

Tags: security, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have question regarding environment variables which are passed through docker-compose file.

I have chaincode which does security checks when security is enabled. It checks if security is enabled through core.SecurityEnabled() api. I enable / disable security using docker-compose env. variable CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED.

This works fine in dev mode. However when I deploy chaincode in non-dev mode, I get core.SecurityEnabled() as false although my env variable is passed as true. I examined the docker containers. Docker container running peer, returns env variable CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=true on env command. However docker container running chaincode does not have env variable CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED. It would be picking up value from core.yaml which is set as false.

Is this as per design? In production mode should we be making changes in core.yaml file rather than to depend on env variable passed through docker-compose?

Comment: No answer from anywhere, so created issue in hyperledger Jira [FAB-1188](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-1188?filter=-2)

Answer (score 0):

I am using the docker-compose as given below to get the **CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=true/false**. Have you tried specifying the environment variables in this manner ?

```
    membersrvc:
      image: hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc
      ports:
        - "7054:7054"
      command: membersrvc
    vp0:
      image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
      ports:
        - "8085:7050"
        - "8080:7053"
        - "30303:30303"
        - "30304:30304"
      environment:
        - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
        - CORE_SECURITY_ENABLED=true
        - CORE_SECURITY_PRIVACY=true
        - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://172.17.0.1:2375
        - CORE_PEER_PKI_ECA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
        - CORE_PEER_PKI_TCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
        - CORE_PEER_PKI_TLSCA_PADDR=membersrvc:7054
        - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
        - CORE_PEER_ID=vp0
        - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLID=test_vp0
        - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLSECRET=MwYpmSRjupbT
      links:
        - membersrvc
      command: sh -c "sleep 35; peer node start  --logging-level=DEBUG"
```

If you got your query answered from the FAB jira, kindly ignore this post.